# Most Ideal Way for Handling JSON Data Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm building an app for iOS devices and would like the app to be able to fetch potentially large amounts of data from a MySQL database using a PHP file that returns a JSON object.

For testing purposes I had model data inside my controller. To begin to use a MVC architecture I want to come up with a way for my model to fetch this data from the database and then allow my controller to display it after being fetched.

For example, say I have a collection of groceries which I can fetch within my `Groceries` object using my `initWithJSON` method. And I wanted to fetch this using AFNetworking.

```
[
  {
    "item": "eggs",
    "color": "white",
    "shape": "oval",
  },
  {
    "item": "bread",
    "color": "brown",
    "shape": "rectangle"
  },
  {
    "item": "cheerios",
    "color": "green/orange",
    "shape": "circle"
  }
]
```

**Would I fetch the JSON inside my `Groceries` object and then create an array and push each grocery item to the array?** And then in my controller would I create my `Groceries` object and call `initWithJSON` and then have my `Groceries.groceryList` array list which was filled with the JSON data. Then populate the UITable in my view with my controller?

What's the *industry standard* way of approaching this method?

Comment: @ghost, In your php controller return the array as json_encode($array);

Answer (score 1):

AfNetworking has a AFJSONSerializer so you can have a parser class that receive data from afnetworking, iterates over all data received and sends each grocery json to Grocery class, which can have an update method to check if this grocery exist, and updates it, and a insert method for new groceries.

Comment: I must not have versed my question correctly. If I have a grocery object, should I be initializing all my "Grocery" objects from within the object or have AFNetworking initialize all my objects outside of the "Grocery" class, making each "Grocery" object as they're fetched from jQuery?